# network configuration

Tags: networking, server, vmware

I created 4 interfaces on Ubuntu server but I can not access the internet from computers belonging to each interface how do I create a bridge for each interface to share the connection

Comment: hmm I want to know too.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get it what configuration you like to meet. should be your Ubuntu server a router for other computers or VMs running on this server ?